# Separating two Ids

Tags: javascript, codeigniter

I need to pass two ids to my ci function. I am using the script below. I have everything set but not the id are passed together as one number. I need a way that I can add a forward slash in between the first and the second ids

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
       $('#example').DataTable({
            "ajax": {
                url : "<?php echo site_url("Single_test/All_presc1/". $id .$cid ) ?>",
                dataType: "json",
                type : 'GET',
                 dom: 'Bfrtip',
            buttons: ['copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print']
            },
        });
    
    });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And what about

```
url : "<?php echo site_url('Single_test/All_presc1/'. $id . '/'. $cid ) ?>",
```